# Counting multidimensional array elements VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, count

I Declared my Array like this:

```
Dim invoice_discountitems(100, 1) As String
```

Now i set values into the array:

```
invoice_discountitems(0,0) = "test1"
invoice_discountitems(0,1) = "test2"
invoice_discountitems(1,0) = "test3"
invoice_discountitems(1,1) = "test4"
```

Now I tried to count the elements:

```
MsgBox(invoice_discountitems.GetLength(0) - 1)
```

But it display the array size (100,1) I want to display (2) elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying the length of the first dimension of the array not the second

```
MsgBox( invoice_discountitems.GetLength(1) ) '  displays 2 '
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx